# No module named ho.pisa - when i run it with wsgi

Tags: django, wsgi, reportlab, pisa

I'am trying to generate PDF from HTML whith Pisa, Reportlab, etc.. and get: 
"No module named ho.pisa" - when i run it with wsgi, but on runserver it works fine.
Somebody have some versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved!
I forgot that i'm using uwsgi without venv and just need to delete 'home /path/to/my/env' string from my_uwsgi_configuration_file.ini